# mysql_num_rows() return 0 when using AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the number of rows based on this query in wordpress:

```
protected function wp_has_facility($fid)
{
    //global $wpdb;

    $fid = intval($fid);

    $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wprf_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '".$fid."' AND meta_key = 'facility_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo $num_rows;

    return $num_rows;
}
```

$num_rows returns 0 when this function is ran.

If I echo the query string and run it in phpmyadmin, it selects successfully giving me a number of rows.

After further investigation it looks like when I hardcode the meta_value it will give me a row count. But if I'm populating the string with variables it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got any entries with meta_key "thing_id" actually, or was it just a placeholder for a var, i.e. `$thing_id`?

Comment: Are you sure that there are datasets which met **both** conditions? Beside that, try out the query in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: A query can be **successful** and return 0 rows. Obviously, your *AND* condition limits the query to 0 rows...i.e, nothing matches the meta_key you are passing it. Try running your queries directly w/ phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench to verify.

Comment: What is thing_id? Did you mean this: $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wprf_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 123 AND meta_key = '$thing_id'") or die(mysql_error()); $num_things = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned - I did try it in phpmyadmin with the AND statement and it does return rows, along with a row count. However in PHP it does not

Comment: The meta_key is supposed to be thing_id

Comment: are u sure that you are putting the 'thing_id' correctly? if you get results in phpmyadmin, then it has to be a problem with that 'thing_id'

Comment: @raygo I copied and pasted the full query string from my PHP script into phpmyadmin. What exactly do you mean by putting?

Comment: Are you sure the code between the two mysql_query("SELECT ... ") functions doesn't initialize another connection or selects another db?

Comment: After further investigation it looks like when I hardcode the meta_value it will give me a row count. But if I'm populating the string with variables it doesn't work.

Comment: @Phill Tidd that means the variable contains something other than what you think it does. However the code you posted uses no variables in the queries.

Comment: I have edited my post to give the actual code I'm using

Answer (score 8):

This only means your table currently contains no record that satisfies both criteria.

#### Remarks about your code:

Concatenation is not necessary, you may replace the query with:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wprf_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$fid' AND meta_key = 'facility_id'";
```

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should avoid using them as they will be removed in a future version of PHP. Here are [the alternatives](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: The same query in phpmyadmin gave me matching records

Comment: I copied and pasted the full query string from my PHP script into phpmyadmin. PHP giving me num_rows of 0, phpmyadmin giving me 1.

Comment: @PhillTidd Please copy and paste it here as well.  Try to `echo` the SQL string, not rownum.

Comment: @dezso `SELECT post_id FROM wprf_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '21' AND meta_key = 'facility_id'`

Comment: @PhillTidd are you sure that `$fid` does not contain a space or something?  And a sidenote: does `meta_value` contain numeric values?  What is its type?  Is it different from `wp_postmeta`?

Comment: @dezso I'm also 100% sure it does not contain spaces. `meta_value` is a longtext data type and yes it does contain numeric values.

And as a note to everyone, lets assume that what I'm explaining is true, that the exact same query works in phpmyadmin, but not executing in php (via either mysql_query, mysqli or Wordpress's $wpdb object). What could cause that?

Comment: Well, if your queries are identical and their result are different, then either the PHP code has some bug (but it seems OK) or you connetct to different databases.  OR there is still the possibility that the two queries differ (I've seen an other version of your question out there, where you used different values in the query (or wasn't it you?)), just it is hard to notice (I've seen questions like that on SO before) - but we can exclude this possibility based on your comment.